# How to handle 3 statuses (pass, fail, and warning) in Gitlab CI/CD?

Tags: c#, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a C# app, the application implementing build job.
after each run the app should return one of the three statuses
passed value 0
failed value -1
warning value 137

This application will be run using the YAML file
part of the YAML file I'm using:

```
Build:
    stage: Build
    <<: 
      - *prefix_build_stage_conf
      - script:
          - {MY_RUN_LINE}
      - allow_failure: 
          exit_codes:
            - 137
      - *post_build_stage_conf
```

According to the example in the GitLab documentation, when the application's exit code is 137, the job should display a warning symbol (!) indicating a warning. If the exit code is -1, the job should fail and display a cross symbol (X). Finally, if the exit code is 0, the job should pass successfully and this is exactly what I need but it is not working for me.

in case of exit status 0 (pass)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQNgz.png)

in case of exit status -1 (fail)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fpu9S.png)

in case of exit status 137 (warning)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNZ1t.png)

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: Thanks for your response 
how to do the expected result as I described 
when i got exit code 137 to see the brown symbol with (!) 
when i got exit code 0 to see the green symbol with (v) 
when i got exit code -1 to see the red symbol with (x) 
I attached few photos above

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "it is not working for me" -- what exactly is not working? What is the unexpected behavior? Your provided example is not reproducible as written.

Comment: sorry if my description is unclear.
the question is:
can I handle a job result in GitLab by the returned exit code from the application? and if yes, how?
for example, if the returned exit code from the application is 0 that means the job passed successfully.
 if the returned exit code from the application is 137 that means the job allow to fail.
 if the returned exit code from the application is -1 that means the job failed.

Comment: The configuration you have for `allow_failure:exit_codes:` seems like it should do exactly that.